# Declare service in AOSP

Tags: android, service, android-source

As part of a training course I need to declare a service in AOSP and call it at boot. The thing is the training is outdated, I'm working on a physical machine and the project is different.

Specs:
Android Version: 12
Android SDK: 31

Anyway I've built a module in C called "exd", it's stored in /system/bin/ and it works properly when called manually. Next I want to declare it as a service.

I've added to init.product.rc file:

```
service exd /system/bin/exd
    oneshot

on boot
    start exd
```

But when I build and download it to the device, service list doesn't display it. And it doesn't start on boot.

Next I've added exd.te file to sepolicy folder:

```
type exd, domain;
type exd_exec, domain;
init_daemon_domain(exd)
```

And added this line to file_contexts:

```
/system/bin/exd u:object_r:exd_exec:s0
```

When I call build it fails with the following message:

```
Error while expanding policy
[ 39% 60/151] //system/sepolicy:sepolicy.recovery Compiling cil files for sepolicy.recovery [common]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery/android_common/sepolicy
out/host/linux-x86/bin/secilc -m -M true -G -c 30 out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/recovery_sepolicy.cil/android_common/recovery_sepolicy.cil -o out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery/android_common/sepolicy_policy -f /dev/null && cp -f out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery/android_common/sepolicy_policy out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery/android_common/sepolicy && rm -f out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery/android_common/sepolicy_policy # hash of input list: 187605db6ee3f7580bafd9adbd0101d2c2a0d02f423bb7efa74ee537c43d35ce
neverallow check failed at out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/recovery_sepolicy.cil/android_common/recovery_sepolicy.cil:8770 from system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:1240
  (neverallow base_typeattr_197 domain (file (execute execute_no_trans entrypoint)))
    <root>
    allow at out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/recovery_sepolicy.cil/android_common/recovery_sepolicy.cil:28846
      (allow init exd_exec (file (read getattr map execute open)))
    <root>
    allow at out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/recovery_sepolicy.cil/android_common/recovery_sepolicy.cil:28848
      (allow exd exd_exec (file (read getattr map execute open entrypoint)))

Failed to generate binary
Failed to build policydb
10:35:34 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I've tried everything I've found on the internet to no avail. The weird thing is that there is another service called "bugreport" which is declared almost indetically as mine, but it is listed after "service list" command.

At this point even pointing a good direction would be great for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting neverallow, which is basically Android saying you are trying to do something that is not allowed in the SEPolicy definition. You need to create a .te file that consists of SEPolicy rules for your service.

An example SEPolicy file can be as follows:

```
type myservice_exec, exec_type, file_type, system_file_type;
typeattribute myservice coredomain;

# myservice servicemanager and binder access
allow shell myservice:binder { call transfer };
allow servicemanager myservice:dir search;
allow servicemanager myservice:file { open read };
allow servicemanager myservice:process getattr;
allow myservice servicemanager:binder { call transfer};
allow myservice system_server:binder call;

init_daemon_domain(myservice)
```

Notice the second line. You are missing that and it is most probably why you are getting a neverallow problem.